# Convert transparent PNG image into transparent JPEG or transparent GIF

Tags: image, png, transparency, jpeg, photoshop

I have a transparent PNG Image. I want to add it as watermark for [this](http://www.bsrsoft.com/) video recording software. But the problem is, software requires jpeg image as a watermark.   When I converted that image to JPEG(using [Pixle Editor](http://pixlr.com/editor/)) it lost its transparency and does no look good in video.
How do I convert Tranparent PNG to Tranparent JPEG?
It doesnt matter how or which tool.

**EDIT:**
How to convert transparent PNG to transparent GIF?

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think jpeg images can have an alpha channel, which means no transparency.

Comment: if you just want to reduce file size, see https://tinypng.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JPEG format does not allow transparency. It does not include an alpha channel. So the answer is : there is no such thing as a transparent JPEG image. Transparency is possible using PNG, GIF or vector based formats, dunno if you can manage the watermark in those?

Comment: So how do I convert it to transparent GIF?

Comment: You will need a photo editing/converting software, Im not sure how Pixle works and/or if you can add the watermark in a GIF file (doubt it).

Comment: Yes this recording s/w supports GIF, JPG, BMP. Pixlr doesnot support GIF. How about photoshop? But i dont know the steps.

Comment: In photoshop, use Save for web, choose GIF and transparent